# iframe sandbox not respecting multiple allow permissions

Tags: html, iframe, adobe, sandbox

I am trying to embed an [Adobe Portfolio](https://portfolio.adobe.com/) into an iframe without much luck. I need to include both images (which appear to have a JS dependency) and links to open in a new window.

The iframe"standbox" directive is not behaving.

I have tried many permutations of other directives and narrowed it down to "allow-scripts" and "allow-popups" that work separately but not together.

I suspect this is something to do with Adobe Portfolio itself but cannot figure out why!?

Please note - code snippet doesn't run fully as expected within stack overflow site - probably because they have their own standbox directive!

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <style>
  .fl {
    width: 300px;
    float: left
  }
  </style>
    <div class="fl">
       <h1>Images working</h1>
       <h3>sandbox="allow-scripts" <br/> (script appear to be needed for images)</h3>
       <iframe src="https://picturelinktest.myportfolio.com" sandbox="allow-scripts" height="350" width="200" ></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl">
      <h1>Link working </h1>
      <h3>sandbox="allow-popups" <br/> works locally but seems not to work in this tool!?!?</h3>
      <iframe src="https://picturelinktest.myportfolio.com" sandbox="allow-popups" height="350" width="200"></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl">
      <h1>Not working when both standbox directives are defined</h1>
      <h3>sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups"</h3>
      <iframe src="https://picturelinktest.myportfolio.com" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups" height="350" width="200" ></iframe>  
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mdn docs says, it valid to keep space seperated value, your code snippet also works fine(as expected) in my Chrome 86.0.4240.183